# Tabbar Items Text Override in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image]Tabbar items text override in large localization strings. I tried below solution and other possible solution but its not working fine. In below solution if number of lines is 2 than its truncate the string properly and don't override but if number of lines is 1 then its override and don't truncate the string properly. Please help to provide any feasible solution, Thanks in advance.

```
 // acess to list of tab bar items
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        items.indices.forEach{
            let viewTabBar = items[$0].value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
            let label = viewTabBar?.subviews[1]as? UILabel
            label?.numberOfLines = 1
            label?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            if $0 == 0{
                label?.text = Messages.shared.OPERATION.uppercased()
            }else if $0 == 1{
                label?.text = Messages.shared.ERROR_INFO.uppercased()
            }else if $0 == 2{
                label?.text = Messages.shared.ENERGY_DATA.uppercased()
            }else if $0 == 3{
                label?.text = Messages.shared.OVERVIEW.uppercased()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make your own custom tabbar, it is easy and flexible

Comment: Thanks @imike but as a temporary solution I truncate the strings hard codedly after required characters.